# Where do function parameters come from in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the following code:

```
  handleOwnerMode = ownerChecked  => {
     this.setState(prev => ({ ownerChecked, showOwner: !prev.showOwner}))
     // this.setState(prev => ({ ownerChecked: !prev.ownerChecked, showOwner: !prev.showOwner }))
  }
```

Inside the render is

```
<Switch onChange={this.handleOwnerMode} checked={this.state.ownerChecked} />
```

`OnChange`, I somehow was able to receive what was changed about `ownerChecked`. Why is this the case? I didn't write `onChange={this.handleOwnerMode(event.value)}` or anything like that...

Also, for `setState`. I normally just use `this.setState( { state: newState} )`, but now I can somehow pass in the previous state with `this.setState( prev => {} )`. Is there defined overloading somewhere that lets me do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> OnChange, I somehow was able to receive what was changed about
>   ownerChecked. Why is this the case? I didn't write
>   onChange={this.handleOwnerMode(event.value)} or anything like that...

In both cases you have passed a function (callback) to "receivers". First time to `Switch` Component, second time to React. Each of them can call  your function/callback using any parameter they want. This is how normally callbacks are used.

> Is there defined overloading somewhere that lets me do this?

Yeah probably `setState` checks if you passed a function to it and behaves differently: e.g. gives you previous state and calls your function. If you pass an object to it, it doesn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

React events are synthetic so that even when yo do not pass any event parameters, function takes it. Take a look at these. [More information 1](https://medium.com/trabe/react-syntheticevent-reuse-889cd52981b6), [More information 2](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html).